# Get Controller of each request

Tags: magento2, controllers, admin-controller

What I want just to print out name of each controller called at a specific request?
So How can I do that any help thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try `controller_action_predispatch` Event :-

**Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="custom_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ControllerActionPredispatch" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Observer\MyClass\ControllerActionPredispatch.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ControllerActionPredispatch implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
       // insert code here
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...It really help me a lot.

Comment: Most Welcome...